# Mysql WHERE IN Comma Separated

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a Mysql/MariaDb Table

```
ID  | name | partner
-----------------------
1     A      2
2     B      1
3     C      5,7
4     D      6,8
5     E      3
6     F      4
7     G      3
8     H      4
```

how to mysql query to search profile of partner with id = 3;
And I want this result purely generated by the query or Stored Procedure/Function.

I have tried like this, but got the error:

> SELECT id, name, partner from table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE id=3);

I want output like this:

```
ID  | name | partner
-----------------------
5     E      3
7     G      3
```

Comment: partner column should be normalized before you can query partner id's like the way you do or use MySQL/MariaDB `FIND_IN_SET()` function

Comment: Yes. See normalisation. Don't bother considering any other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sub-query you use:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id=3
```

So your query becomes:

```
SELECT id, name, partner from table WHERE id IN (3);
```

But I guess you need:

```
SELECT partner FROM table WHERE id=3
```

Which results into:

```
SELECT id, name, partner from table WHERE id IN ('5,7');
```

Notice that this is a string and cannot be used in the `IN` function.

So you should, as mentioned by others, use `find_in_set` like so:

```
SELECT id, partner from docs WHERE FIND_IN_SET (3, partner) > 0;
```

Comment: Was just about to post about the same. Nice explanation of the current situation and how to fix it. One Thing you might add, would be to run the subquery for the IN statement on it's own to see what data that returns.

Comment: And how do you plan to handle the comma separated values?

Comment: Thank you to all of you.
After many attempts, apparently the comma separated value should not be spaced.
`value: 3, 7 -> this error
value: 3,7 -> this is successful`

Comment: The normalisation should be the accepted answer, not this. Even if you go down this route, the find_in_set() was suggested by sy else way ahead of this answer and is described in the duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your `partner` field is comma separated string which contains IDs you have to use function `FIND_IN_SET`, and your query must looks like this:

```
SELECT id, name, partner from table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, partner) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A normalised schema might be as simple as the following...

```
ID  | name | partner
-----------------------
1     A      2
2     B      1
3     C      5
3     C      7
4     D      6
4     D      8
5     E      3
6     F      4
7     G      3
8     H      4
```

...but more probably, it will involve splitting the partners out to a separate table.